# C#: Size of the object for class implementing interfaces

Tags: c#, class, interface

I recently came across C# question stated as below:

> A class implements two interfaces each containing three methods. The
>   class contains no instance data. Which of the following correctly
>   indicate the size of the object created from this class?

The answer that it says is **24** bytes.
I don't understand how? What would be the size if both the interfaces have some members which have same declarations?

Comment: 24bytes? 24bits?  If the interfaces have the same members then they’ll only need to be implemented once on the derived class to satisfy the interface implementation

Comment: @maccettura [edit] 24 bytes

Comment: An even better answer... who cares (assuming this isn't for school). If you are worrying about the amount of space *methods* take up, you have bigger problems.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I agree with you, but sometimes we have to care just for interview's sake.

Comment: The only per-instance members are non-static fields. Anything else do not depend on how many instance you have.

Comment: @Codingman If someone asked me that at interview, I'd want *them* to answer BradleyDotNET's question first.